# How to calculate weighted average inside an ArrayFormula based on multiple row-criteria?

Tags: google-sheets, average, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I'm trying to solve a problem for so long and I haven't figured out how to do this.

Basically, I need to calculate a weighted average based on multiple criteria. This criteria is going to be retrieved from a `ArrayFormula` (It means that I have columns with different values for the criterias, and I want to automatically fill the average based on that criteria using `ArrayFormula`).

This is my structure on the "main" table: [Main Table Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XxfQ3.png)

And that is the table that I'm "searching" on: [Search Table Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wtl9S.png)

The "search" table works like a balance with all the operations made by the users. It contains all purchases and sells, with their correspondent prices and quantities.

Basically, I need the purchased price weighted average by user and ticker, where the prices are the values and the quantities are the weights. Using the above images as an example: "Calculate the weighted average purchased price for ticker ABEV3 that belongs to example@example.com". But that has to iterate to every row, using `ArrayFormula.`

Before implementing `ArrayFormula`, I was using queries successfully, but I found out that `QUERY` and `ArrayFormula` are incompatible when using a "Array" on the `WHERE` clause. I tried to use `SUMPRODUCT` as well, pairing it with `FILTER`, but it returns a size mismatch error.

Important to mention:
On the "main" table, it's possible to have the same ticker for different users, but not the same ticker on the same user twice. It works like a composite primary key, as in databases.

Thanks in advance!

A copy of my sheet is available [here.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DtWEbTU_nnw2EshaDXPlj-IAJECiYa__hiL5p0t_fik/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: @player0 Forgot to include it on the question. It's [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DtWEbTU_nnw2EshaDXPlj-IAJECiYa__hiL5p0t_fik/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: A solution using [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script) fits you?

Comment: @albertovielma Sure, I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I managed to do a workaround.

I created another sheet to hold all sums and grouped queries.

On that sheet, I query the transactions sheets twice, one for buy operations and another for sell operations, grouping them by user and ticker. The result is something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sje9c.png).

After that, the rows on that sheet automatically update once a transaction is added, and it's just a matter of doing a `VLOOKUP` on that query interval.

Why it was good for me?
Because I need the totals for other purposes, and this satisfies both problems.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A&B2:B; QUERY(FILTER({
 'Transactions - Variable Income'!A2:A&'Transactions - Variable Income'!B2:B\ 
 'Transactions - Variable Income'!D2:D*'Transactions - Variable Income'!E2:E}; 
 'Transactions - Variable Income'!C2:C="buy"); 
 "select Col1,avg(Col2) group by Col1"); 2; 0)))
```

[image: 0]

**(https://www.wallstreetmojo.com/average-vs-weighted-average/)**

Comment: While waiting for an answer, I managed to do an workaround: I summarized all the data on queries on the same transactions sheet, grouping by user and ticker. Then, I did a VLOOKUP on that queries.

Your answer is not working correctly, because if I change the quantities it gives me a wrong weighted average, as seen [here.](https://i.ibb.co/V9K8H4f/A.png)

Comment: I can fix it for you if you share your sheet again

Comment: @GabrielSobral, if you're satisfied with your workaround, please consider to share it as an answer so if other people have the same doubt can see the answer.

Comment: @albertovielma Sure, I'll post it here soon, it was indeed very useful for a lot of other things that I needed to do.